# Does the Web Developer toolbar really have a Save button to save CSS modified in Firebug?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug, web-developer-toolbar

According to [this S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162644/why-cant-i-save-css-changes-in-firebug/168927#168927) the Firefox Web Developer toolbar has a Save button:

However, the answer shows an image of the toolbar which does not show a Save button:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/images/t/11916/943948800))</sub>

I just installed the toolbar to take advantage of this option but I do not see a Save button.

Does the Save button exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you actually edit the CSS there is a "Save" button on the window:[alt text http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/6628/screenshotdoesthewebdev.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/6628/screenshotdoesthewebdev.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try http://cssUpdater.com which saves your css while you change in FireBug.

This way you can develop in FireBug, hit the "Sync now" button from within the FireBug panel. And reload the page to see that your changes is still present!