# extension like firebug to actually write on the file system

Tags: css, firefox, firebug

I'm not a desktop applications developer so I was wondering if someone heard about an extension that actually writes on the file system. it would be great if you open firebug like extension and do some modifications e.g. adding CSS rules and they will be added automatically in the CSS file. how hard would it be to build such an extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I've found is [XRefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/) which actively monitors files for changes, then automatically refreshes Firefox. It feels very similar to editing live with FireBug.

I think an extension like this would be possible, but it would be pretty hard to map DOM changes to a specific stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can could use the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) for this.

The changes you make in its CSS editor (`CSS > Edit CSS`) are applied to the page immediately (without saving to file), but it also has a `Save...` option, so you can overwrite the existing CSS file with it.

It's a pretty basic text field, though, that just displays the plain CSS file. It doesn't have any syntax highlighting nor organize the CSS rules according to the cascade etc. like Firebug does.

Also see this related question:

- [Why can’t I save CSS changes in FireBug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162644/why-cant-i-save-css-changes-in-firebug)

Answer (score 1):

Use Backfire. It's an open source solution I wrote that sends CSS changes back to the server and saves them. It has a working .NET server implementation example that is easily portable to any other platform.

http://blog.quplo.com/2010/08/backfire-save-css-changes-made-in-firebug/