# FireDiff Alternative for Chrome

Tags: dom, firebug

For those who dont know what firediff is, its a firefox plugin that integrates into firebug to allow you to track all dom changes.

http://www.incaseofstairs.com/firediff/ and

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firediff/

However, I dont overly like debugging in firefox, and much prefer Chrome.

Is there however an alternative to this as an extension that works from  your browser and not from within a plugin like watch.js

I tried googling "Dom Change Chrome Extention" and "Monitoring DOM Changes in Chrome" and such but they all require to add javascript plugins to your websites. However I'd like an extension to work across everything, just like firediff

Answer (score 1):

Was wondering the same thing and found the answer here:

[Export CSS changes from inspector (webkit, firebug, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355111/export-css-changes-from-inspector-webkit-firebug-etc)

Apparently Chrome already contains this functionality built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I made a Chrome extension that does exactly this for CSS. It doesn't track HTML changes though, other than for style tags and inline styles.

It's called [StyleURL](https://www.styleurl.app) - it diffs CSS changes you make in Chrome Inspector and outputs valid CSS: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/styleurl/emplcligcppnlalfjknjbanolhlnkmgp

Here's an example where I added `padding-bottom: 50px` to Stack Overflow:
[image: StyleURL example diff]

It's open-source and on GitHub too: https://github.com/Jarred-Sumner/styleurl-extension