# Disable automatic saving of CSS changes in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am referring to the save feature in the 'Sources' panel of the Chrome Dev Tools. I have been using this feature for a long time in the stable release of Chrome, but after installing the build from the developer channel, I notice that once I have saved the file the first time, Chrome no longer prompts me to save and just does it automatically after every change I make.

This is quite a pain, as I make a lot of changes experimentally in the dev tools whilst debugging which I don't wish to save, I would like Chrome to save the file only when I explicitly tell it to.

Does anyone know if there is a way to disable this automatic CSS saving?

(Apologies for no screenshot, my PrtScn key seemingly won't operate when I am in a context menu)

**Update:**

I have reverted to the current stable build, 27.0.1453.93, and the behaviour appears to be the same.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: Alas, I learned after reading a post by Google's dev relations person that the automatic save cannot be disabled and it seems that's the way it's going to stay.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013/

Comment: Yes, same problem here. This is a great feature, but we need a way to temporarily disable it (something easier then going through the whole process of un-mapping/remapping), to be able to do one or two test. Plus there is a bug in Chrome that corrupts unicode characters in my style sheet, so after a few saves I have to go in and fix these characters manually.

Comment: +1 All or nothing is rather brutal. You should be able to tell Chrome "I'm testing now, don't save" from time to time, or alternatively save at the press of a button rather than automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alas, I learned after reading a post by Google's dev relations person
>   that the automatic save cannot be disabled and it seems that's the way
>   it's going to stay.
>   [html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013](http://html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/revolutions2013)

–  [tommypyatt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138468/tommypyatt) Feb 21 '14 at 14:22

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same problem, I can only offer workarounds: use another browser, such as Firefox, for doing tests!

Alternatively you could launch another instance of Chrome with a different profile. You could also launch a Chrome "Incognito Window", it seems to not apply the filesystem mappings.

I normally use an Incognito Window or inline styles to test changes.

Comment: You must reply the solution, not a workaround. Its is possible by removing folder from workspace in sources tab

Answer (score 2):

While not solving the issue directly, it is a decent work around:

In Chrome, in the css inspector you can click and hold the + button, then choose to add your changes to the inspector-stylesheet.  It's not as convenient as directly editing in your css-selectors, but what you write will all be in inspector-stylesheet.css, so not saved to your project.  Then when you are happy with your changes, you can manually put them in to your css.