# How to export CSS modifications made in Firefox Dev Tools?

Tags: css, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I've made a number of CSS changes to the page in Firefox Dev Tools.  I would like to export these changes somehow.

Is there a way to do it?

P.S. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355111/export-css-changes-from-inspector-webkit-firebug-etc) for mostly Chrome from 8 years ago.

Comment: it seems to be the same thing, click on the file name, hit save and you will be prompted to save the file locally.