# No CSS changes in the "changes" tab in Chrome's Console drawer

Tags: css, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-dev-server

I would really love to see all my live css changes summarized somewhere in Chrome browser, there are a couple of question about this at SO, but nothing works for me. Especially this particular answers which seems to be the most straightforward way to achieve what I need.

[**Export CSS changes from inspector (webkit, firebug, etc)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58929803/1531116)

I've changed a few css properties, but don't see anything in this tab:

[image: Example Screenshot]

FYI - I'm using webpack dev server to serve this page if that's relevant

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I make my changes appear:

Once you select the element to modify click the + sign under the styles tab.

The new inspector style sheet appears under the changes tab in the left hand column. The right hand pane includes your new changes.

[image]

Comment: So it doesn't automatically track and collect which changes have already been made? That's... an odd choice.

Comment: @Aron Apparently the Changes tab only works for styles that live in a CSS file. When using Webpack, by default the styles are injected as inline `style` tags, and changes to those don't appear in the Changes tab. So that's why this is necessary.

Comment: Lame. It seems you have to make these changes via that "New Style Rule" icon, so they end up in the inspector-stylesheet. Changes made directly to displayed rules or element.style don't show up. Again, lame, but I can adjust. Lamer still, is that they're doc doesn't specify this. That said, it's anything but lame that we can, at least, propose changes. Which I've just done here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/changes/

Answer (score 0):

If you made css changes in the Inspect > Elements pane, and didn't happen to use the method of https://stackoverflow.com/a/69634283/6200445 , then one way to see the changes is to do a git compare of the DOM structures.   Its not a perfect solution, but you can compare the dom structures (via edit HTML on ) in two commits, comparing some baseline (commit) with your live css changes (second commit)

In my case the git compare had a few irrelevant changes but it caught all my css changes.