# How to edit and SAVE static webpages from browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor, firebug

I had been using Dreamweaver in Windows. 
Recently I shifted to Ubuntu, there I cant find any good alternative to Dreamweaver.

So I decided to use Firebug but Its good for editing CSS, Javascript. I dont find it useful for editing HTML (in place).
**1. Is there any way that can enable inplace editing of text in browser itself?**

The problem I faced with firebug is that I am unable to save the edited CSS files or js files.
2. Is there any way that can enable saving of edited data in firebug?
**2nd one Answered: [Why can't I save CSS changes in Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162644/why-cant-i-save-css-changes-in-firebug)**

Note:
I have already tried Kompozer, NVU and Quanta Plus.

**EDIT:**
I am aware that webpages in remote server can not be edited directly in browser. I am talking about editing a local copy OR editing any webpage and saving a local copy of it.

Comment: Why not use an editor and just F5? You'll be a *lot* more productive with something like Vim once you get past the learning curve.

Comment: Have you tried [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)? There's some information about running Dreamweaver on Wine [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/AdobeDreamweaver).

Comment: @Demian Brecht: I mentioned in the question that I cant find any good alternative for Dreamweaver in Linux. If you know one plz suggest. I have tried Kompozer, NVU and Quanta Plus.

Comment: @icktoofay: Latest Dreamweaver is not supported, and I am really looking for alternative of dreamweaver. Also wine takes alot of resources.

Comment: If you explained what _features_ you are missing, you might get a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for css you could use [web developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/). Install it, press ctrl+shift+e and there you go.

Comment: Worked fine but found nothing to edit text in browser itself and exporting the code.

Comment: To edit the text you will use firebug. However, you should do this only for quick edits, not on a regular basis.

Comment: @lonut: How would I save the edited data from firebug to my disk? I dont think firebug provides such option.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this: [Why can't I save CSS changes in FireBug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162644/why-cant-i-save-css-changes-in-firebug)

Though there are good alternative editors that can be used to do many things that the dreamweaver can do, they never offer the comfort of Dreamweaver. You can install [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) and [run dreamweaver on ubuntu](http://www.noob2geek.com/linux/how-to-install-and-run-dreamweaver-cs4-in-ubuntu/). There's also [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/), which is actually made by the W3C. I imagine it's also very light-weight and probably not even of the same caliber as Kompozer, but since it's the W3C's own creation then at least you can be certain that what you create with it is valid, if potentially simple.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Yes, you can edit text within the browser itself via this ["Lord of the Web" JavaScript snippet](http://www.blogohblog.com/cool-javascript-tricks/):**

```
document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on';
```

*for best results (JavaScript support from the address bar is spotty):*

1. Use Chrome or Firefox
2. Enter snippet into browser's built-in JavaScript console (Firebug also works)
3. "Save as" web page, complete. (Note: paths to resources like JS scripts, CSS and image files may be modified.) I have confirmed the changes are preserved when saving to a local file from Chrome and Firefox.

---

**2. Chrome now supports [Live editing CSS, then saving to disk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qy5obNItQiQ)**

1. Make changes to styles, as you do...
2. You can click through to the Sources pane and live-edit styles there, just like a text editor.
3. Right click and save to disk. choose where to save the file
4. Make some more changes
5. Just hit ctrl-s (or cmd-s) to immediately save back to disk in the same location.

Answer (score -1):

You can't edit in place in the browser as this would be a security risk - if this was possible, you could edit any website in the world...

I suggest using a dedicated HTML editor - there are many such for linux as well.

Comment: I think he meant to edit the page and then manually save it back to his hard drive.

Comment: @RAHUL PRASAD - instead of downvoting someone for not understanding your question, perhaps re-read your question and edit it to be more understandable. However, I **did** understand the question. You simply don't like the answer.

Comment: @Oded: Your first line is so obvious, "you can edit any website in the world!", Do you think level of my question is soo low? I want to edit and save locally. BTW I got this downVote power recently so dont know when and where I should use it. Thats why I voted down cuz I did not like it

Comment: @RAHUL PRASAD - "I did not like it" is probably the worst reason to downvote. Would you downvote an answer that told you that a coding practice was bad, even if it was correct, simply because you didn't like the answer? As for what you call "obvious" - perhaps to you it is, but not to everyone (and this site is read by many people) and I don't and can't know what is and isn't obvious to you. See this meta question and answer for what others think should be downvoted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16236/when-should-correct-answers-get-downvoted

Comment: @Oded: Okay I made a mistake, if you edit your post I'll be able to undo the down-vote.