# How to save firebug changes using Eclipse (Windows)?

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, firebug

How to save [firebug](https://web.archive.org/web/20101226133037/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) changes using Eclipse (Windows)?

I found here that [it's possible to save firebug changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162644/why-cant-i-save-css-changes-in-firebug/162738#162738) if we use Eclipse and [FireEclipse](https://web.archive.org/web/20120626140258/http://www.almaden.ibm.com/u/bartonjj/fireclipse/index.html)

Is anyone using this combination successfully? Can anyone explain the step of Installing?

I'm on Windows7 64 bit

And if FireEclipse works with Eclipse then Will it also work with Aptana port of Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

First, whether it will work on Aptana? Yes, it should.

Now to the main question: The Fireclipse site claims contrary to what the answer you have linked to cites: the FE site claims that it mainly helps in debugging javascript through Firebug and Eclipse consoles (nothing about exporting/saving CSS changes).

Also, I wouldn't really recommend going with this plugin 'coz it hasn't been updated in a while. According to SourceForge (where the [source of this project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fireclipse/) is hosted), Fireclipse was last updated 2008-10-22. Unless, you are still using Firefox 2 and Eclipse 3.2, you should avoid this plugin.

Try some of the other tools listed in that thread, for example, [FireDiff](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firediff/) sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i save my firebug changes.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firediff/

Hope this helps.