# save CSS - while browsing, how can I save the css files from inside chrome dev or firebug to local directory

Tags: javascript, css, save, local

while browsing asite, ***how can I save the CSS and javascript files from inside chrome dev*** or firebug to my local machine directory

Let me clarify, I'm not looking to save on the remote server. I can see the resources, but there's no option to save them.

1. Can you please help explain if I can save, (rather that copy and
   paste)
2. Are there any plugins to save the resources

Comment: Hmmm, hope this helps you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162644/why-cant-i-save-css-changes-in-firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome Dev-tools: Under the Sources tab, right-click the file and click "Save as"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Awesome, I had the old version. Also, the newer sites are posting html, without the extension, and the html content save does not capture the HTML, any ways around it.