# Is there a way to save a webpage once i've edited out the elements only using FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I've been toying with the Inspect element in FireFox and i'm getting decent at using it's tools to find advertisements and delete there nodes from the script. I'm wondering if there is a way for me to save the page with out the nodes I deleted so that I may load the page every time without those specific Nodes being loaded again?

I understand there are Add Block tools designed to to this I was just curious.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a page you are viewing on the internet in general, and have edited, and you want those changes to persist? In that case, you might want to consider Grasemonkey, which will let you write a script to remove the elements you don't want when the page loads.

Comment: You need tons of matching-lists. This is how the adblockers work too. It's not healthy to try this individually :P Unless you target specific advertisement wrappers, it might be best to not even attempt it :)

Comment: Some dreams shouldn't watch to feel batter in future :P

Comment: Niet the Dark, Yes that is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: See also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077217/is-there-a-way-to-save-css-js-changes-of-remote-resource-between-page-reloads-or/ ?