# Unable to edit javascript in Chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am attempting to edit some javascript code that is in the html of the page (not an imported js file).  I am able to set break points and step through them, but I can not edit the javascript during the execution or before/after execution. I prettified ({}) and un-prettified the files.  The code piece is not minified in this section.

1. Can I do this?
2. Does it matter that the code is inside an attached event.  Ie a click etc.
3. I am useing jquery obviously.

I could have sworn this used to be a common feature.  But it has been over a year since I have done a lot of javascript.

Comment: Is the `javascript` in existing `html` page , or only run at `console` ?

Comment: The javascript is in the html of the page.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077217/is-there-a-way-to-save-css-js-changes-of-remote-resource-between-page-reloads-or/ ,

Comment: The problem with that is all of them are creating full "workspaces" and doing a lot more then what I want.  I know that I used to be able to make small changes to my javascript and see it work from the dev tools.  Is this just not possible any more?  do I have to create a full workspace just to do simple changes?

Comment: It does definitely still work. Try moving your code into a separate JavaScript file. After prettifying you won't be able to edit "script.js:formatted", but you can edit the minified "script.js" file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using chromium / chrome there are several methods to modify the `html` of an existing `document`. At devtools

- Select `Elements` tab, right click on the element to modify, select `Edit as HTML` , make modifications in frame containing element, then click outside of editor frame
- Select `Sources` tab, select `Snippets` tab, right click and select `New` , write `javascript`, to execute in existing `window` press `▶` at right panel to run `javascript` in `Snippets` middle panel in existing `window`. For example if `$("body").on("click", function() {alert(123)})` is added as a `Snippet` clicking `body` element should call `alert(123)`. The event should also be listed in `Event Listeners` at right panel of devtools when inspecting element. Removing the listener may be somewhat more challenging; even if you click `remove` when hovering over the listener at right panel, as the event is already attached to the element. The simplest method would be to add a `namespace` to the event `$("body").on("click.abcnamespace", handler)`, then call `$("body").off("click.abcnamespace")`
- Modifying text existing handlers will not automatically affect , or cancel the event handler previously attached to the element. The simplest approach would be to copy and save existing `javascript` containing event handler, select `Elements` tab , right click on element that has event listener, select `Event Listeners` at right panel, when hovering over the `window`, `document` or `HTMLElement` having event attached a button should be displayed that says `Remove`. Click that button to remove the event listener. You should then be able to modify the saved event listener and add it back to the existing `document` with modifications being applied