# Saving CSS changes on REMOTE HOST using development tools?

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

There is a bunch of possibilities to save CSS and HTML changes made using chrome devtools (eg. with Tincr) or using firebug BUT only on local host.

Questions have been asked long ago* about this, but there might be hopefully some updates since.

Is there a way to upload the changes made for instance using chrome devTools to a website hosted on a remote server? (Like filezila does on FTP)

Would it be possible (and safe) to save these changes via a PHP script that would provide FTP and DB login ; a script that would work with one or another development tools?

*:
2008 : [Why can't I save CSS changes in Firebug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162644/why-cant-i-save-css-changes-in-firebug) 
2011 : [How to save CSS changes of Styles panel of Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843495/how-to-save-css-changes-of-styles-panel-of-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 1):

Most of these extensions are experimental and do not have a large developer base. What that translates to is that they are buggy and pretty much unreliable. And there is good reason for that -  The browser does not know the language/technology/platform that spits out the HTML/CSS that it renders. If you are using a dynamic language to generate the HTML, then saving the edited CSS/HTML using browser tools is pretty much useless, because you will still have to go into the code files/data source and make corresponding edits.

If the browser developers thought that there was real value add, they would have added an option in the dev tools itself without having communities build extensions for that.

The way I use dev tools/firebug is, I make changes, see in real time the impact, have the code files open with me at the same time, and make changes in them as well. All is good.

My two cents.. :)

Comment: thanks for your answer! "If you are using a dynamic language to generate the HTML", I'm not sure to understand but if you are talking about plain text vs rich text, it seems safe since I'm just interested  to edit in plain text, and CSS. For the same reasons I don't understand that one "The browser does not know the language/technology/platform that spits out the HTML/CSS that it renders". Changing plain text in a DB field, or CSS in a .css should not be that complicated and risky.

Comment: So my backup question is: is there a way to save these changes locally first, and then using a software to apply these changes -while keeping the website on remote host-?

Comment: I guess I wasn't fully clear - I meant if you are using say .NET/PHP/Java/Python/Ruby or a plethora of other languages to generate the HTML/CSS code. As for saving these locally, you could edit the HTML in the ELEMENTS tab of dev tools, then select the root element and say 'Copy as HTML' then paste it to a local file. Same can be done from the STYLES tab on the right side of dev tools for CSS.